# nginx rewrite all posts but not css or js

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a WordPress blog, and I'd like to redirect all requests to one certain post/page, excluding js, css (and images).

so example.com/some-post/ must redirect (temporarily) to exmaple.com/catch-all/

I was playing around with this, but doesn't quite seem to work (I'm not sure I need to use $uri):

```
if ($uri !~ \.css$) {
        set $redi C;
}

if ($uri !~ \.js$) {
        set $redi "($redi)J";
}

if ($uri !~ /catch-all/$) {
        set $redi "($redi)P";
}

if ($redi = CJP) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com/catch-all/ last;
        return 302;
}
```

Comment: do not use `if ($uri` - use `location `

Comment: but you can't use location != /catch-all/$ as far as I know?

Comment: regular expressions have thing called `negative look behind`. BTW do you really need `!= /catch-all/$`?

Comment: With the IFs if I wouldn't include != /catch-all it would redirect that page as well (endless loop).

Answer (score 7):

Use empty `location` blocks to avoid the redirect for certain requests:

```
location ~ \.css$ {}
location ~ \.js$ {}
location /catch-all/ {}
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /catch-all/ redirect;
}
```